# Different font color active tab Firefox

Tags: firefox, colors, tabs

I've done some reading about changing the font color of an active tab in Firefox through css. However, I do not seem able to get it right. It looks as if the font color of the inactive tabs command is leading, which makes the font color of the active tab the same color. That means an orange font color in a red tab. I would like the font color in the active tab to be black.

`userChrome.css`

```
/* color active tab; red */ 
.tab-background[selected="true"] { background-attachment: none!important; background-color: red!important; background-image: none!important;}

/* font color active tab; black */
TabsToolbar .tabbrowser-tab[selected] {color: black !important;}

/* color non-active tabs; black */ 
tab:not([selected=”true”]) { background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important; color: black !important;}

/* font color non-active tabs; orange */
TabsToolbar .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=”true”]) {color: rgb(255, 128, 0) !important;}
```

Everything works fine, except for the font color in the red active tab. What can I do to make this happpen?

Comment: `selected=”true”` has the wrong quotes (do no use smart quotes in code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Everything works fine, except for the font color in the red active tab

You are using the wrong kind of quotes. Smart quotes are not (normally) used in code.

Corrected code:

```
TabsToolbar .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected="true"]) {color: rgb(255, 128, 0) !important;}
```